# Cannot Install TinyTeX package

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

I’m using R, RStudio but new to r-markdown and want to produce document in pdf/latex. I was a little rebutted by the installing the complete version of MiKTeX and was relief reading the solution proposed by Yihui Xie with [TinyTeX](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) and think this is exactly the solution for (people like) me. Unfortunately, I failed to install the package and don’t understand what am I doing wrong. I carefully read the instructions on TinyTeX vignette  for a “R USER” (I tried to install through R Studio). Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you. More info below
Commands I ran in RStudio:

```
install.packages(c('tinytex', 'rmarkdown'))  
tinytex::install_tinytex().
```

I see downloading action and some of the package but it is incomplete. I have the following message:

```
Starting to install TinyTeX to C:\Users\XXX\Documents\R\R\R->UserLibrairies. It will take a few minutes. 

PATH=C:\Users\XXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyKB2Ys\install-tl-20180525\tlpkg\tlperl\bin;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Acronis\CommandLineTool\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\FileProtector64\;C:\Program Files\Acronis\PyShell\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;c:\unknownDDEPath;c:\unknownDDEPath\DDE;C:\blp\DAPI;C:\blp\DAPI\DDE.  
    "C:\Users\XXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyKB2Ys\install-tl-20180525\install-tl" -profile=../texlive.profile
    Automated TeX Live installation using profile: ../texlive.profile
    Loading http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb  
    **'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
    operable program or batch file.**   
    **'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**
    C:\Users\XXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyKB2Ys\install-tl-20180525\install-tl: TLPDB::from_file could not download http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb;
    C:\Users\XXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyKB2Ys\install-tl-20180525\install-tl: maybe the repository setting should be changed.
    TinyTeX installed to C:\Users\XXX\Documents\R\R\R-UserLibrairies  
    Restart your R session and check if tinytex:::is_tinytex() is TRUE.
```

When I restart and test with > tinytex:::is_tinytex() I got

```
Warning messages:
1: In file.remove("TinyTeX/install-tl.log") :
  cannot remove file 'TinyTeX/install-tl.log', reason 'No such file or directory'   
2: running command '"bin/win32/tlmgr" install latex-bin xetex amscls amsfonts amsmath bibtex booktabs caption dvipdfmx ec etoolbox fancyvrb fontspec framed geometry graphics graphics-def gsftopk hyperref ifluatex ifxetex lm luaotfload makeindex mathspec metafont mfware natbib oberdiek titling tools upquote url xkeyval zapfding' had status 127.   
3: running command '"bin/win32/tlmgr" path add' had status 127     
4: running command '"bin/win32/tlmgr" conf auxtrees add "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/share/texmf"' had status 127  

version info
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default locale:  
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  
  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
  LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252  
  LC_NUMERIC=C  
  LC_TIME=English_United States.1252  
  attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    
loaded via a namespace (and not attached): 
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3
```

Comment: `Note that when we say tinytex (lower case), we mean the R package. TinyTeX means the LaTeX distribution`

Comment: Did you install `tinytex` or `TinyTex`?

Comment: You might also need to install `wget` and set the correct PATH http://noahcoad.com/post/614/using-wget-on-windows

Comment: @Tung: Thank you  for the wget. I didn't know about it. I will install and set the PATH. I try again the installation.  I want to install tinytex, the R package. I understand it will install all packages require by MiKTex.

Comment: Update: I installed `wget` ans set the `PATH` accordingly. This helped as I managed to go further in the installation. Unfortunately I'm still unable to compile:  tinytex::pdflatex('test.tex')  
    Error: Failed to compile test.tex.